# Initialize a new data disk in azure VM with template

Tags: azure, azure-vm-templates

We are trying to automate the deploy of an azure virtual machine, right now we have a template that creates the VM with 4 data disks, but after the deployment is done we have to rdp the machine and go to Disk management and initialize the disk one by one manually.

Is there a way to initialize the disks with a template without having to log into the machine and do it manually?

Comment: Is it a Windows or linux VM? You have a way to run some powershell or bash script with an extension for this purpose.

Comment: Its a windows VM - windows server 2016 datacenter.